# Classic ASP form resubmit

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I have a search page which fetches thousands of records based on user inputs.
I am trying to implement pagination by loading each page records dynamically using Classic ASP.

Here I have 2 ASP pages.In my first ASP page user will have textbox and dropdown controls to enter inputs.After clicking on Search button user will be navigated to next page.

In the second page based on page size and page index i should call a Stored procedure and fetch records of the respective page.

Here my page has Next(>) and Prev(<) links to navigate from one page to another.
When user clicks on any of the above links(>,<) how can i calculate page index(Page Number) and resubmit same form(page) to again hit database and fetch records.

When form is resubmitted already taken previuos page Input values values are losing scope since for first hit i received values using Query Index.
From next hits onwards since same form is resubmitted not able to capture values and pass parameters to Stored Procedure.
Please help me on this how to approach.

Comment: The most common approach for this kind of task is to use a cookie. If you need to support cookieless browsing you could mimic the ASP.NET viewstate in a hidden form field containing your search parameters and paging info.

Comment: pass page index and page size as parameter

Comment: @Zam That's an invitation for having your site scraped. If you're aware and okay with this (an all the misuse usually following) it's indeed the simplest way to pass the needed params around.

Comment: @Filburt -- I cannot agree with you. Because you mush always check that passed parameters is valid and in bound. Other way -- store you settings in Session("XXX") variables

Comment: @Zam You are mistaking my warning to be about some kind of injection. My point was about having 3rd party sites using paging url parameters to constantly grab data form your site causing unwanted traffic and possibly diluting your advertising banner click-through rate. Using server-side session variables as you suggested will indeed help to verify queries sent to your site.

Comment: @Filburt. For avoid such situation "3rd party sites using paging url parameters to constantly grab data form your site" I am always checking referer url. If it outside my domain, then "bye-bye"!

Comment: @Zam Sadly this will lock out valid users trying to bookmark the result list. I've dealt with these issues quite a bit on a high traffic Classic ASP site 15 years ago. In any case this is far beyond the OP issue and most of the scrapers can be convinced to use a dedicated Web API instead. Your initial comment suggests a valid approach and my comment was merely intended to raise the OP's awareness.

Comment: @Filburt Yes it's true. User will be not able to bookmark page. Ok, other suggestion -- encrypt parameters, or, as was mentioned before, keep some settings in Session(XX) variables.

Comment: im sorry, but what is the problem with paging with a URL scheme or querystring?  This is standard practice, and how google also iterates through your pages.   Not having this functionality because you are worried about scraping can be solved in so many other ways.   Sessions are probably the WORST solution.